# Modify Gridpanel columns

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

How can I modify my columns in my gridpanel?

Initially, I create my gridpanel with empty columns, since they will be added dynamically later.

```
Ext.define( 'My.grid.Panel', {
  extend    : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  columns: []
  ...
```

After creating and rendering `My.grid.Panel`, I now want to add columns to this panel.

```
var arGridColumns = [
        Ext.create( 'Ext.grid.column.Column', {
           text: 'A', 
           dataIndex: 'name'
        } ),
        Ext.create( 'Ext.grid.column.Column', {
           text: 'B', 
           dataIndex: 'value', 
           flex: 1
        } )
     ];

myGridPanel.columns = arGridColumns;
myGridPanel..doLayout();
```

But that does not change anything.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Columns array with the order of the columns you want, and then call the reconfigure method of the Grid. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure